# How do I remove a character of strings in a list if it ends with (character)?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, ends-with

Hello I am trying to remove the Character '+'

```
>>> a = ['eggs+', 'I don't want to remove this ', 'foo', 'spam+', 'bar+']
>>> a = [i[:-1] for i in a if i.ends with('+')]
>>> a
    ['eggs', 'spam', 'bar']
>>>
```

why are "I don't want to remove this" and the like 
getting removed and how do I just remove the '+' 
and leave every thing else like

```
>>>['eggs', 'I don't want to remove this ', 'foo', 'spam', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = ['eggs+', 'I dont want to remove this ', 'foo', 'spam+', 'bar+']
a = [i[:-1] if i.endswith('+') else i for i in a]
a

['eggs', 'I dont want to remove this ', 'foo', 'spam', 'bar']
```

You had some syntax issues, the if else must come before the iteration.